# what positive numbers $a,b,c,d $ makes $\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d}$ bounded in every neighbourhood of $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I was playing with $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d}$  for $a,b,c,d ,x,y >0 $ and realised that $\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d}$ is bounded in every neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ if $c=2a , d=2b$ because the $AM-GM$ inequality so is it the only case where $z:=\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d}$ bounded ?
it is easy to see that eventually $x,y <1$ so if $z$ is bounded for some $a,b,c,d$ then any $a_1>a$ and $b_1>b$ and $c_1<c$ and $d_1<d$ would also work

if $c=2a$ and $d>2b$ then the denominator will be $\frac{x^{a}}{y^b} +\frac{y^{b + \epsilon}}{x^a}$ choose some $0<k<\frac{a}{b+\epsilon }$ $y^{b } = x ^{a-k\epsilon}$ it follows that as $x \to 0$  $ \ z \to \infty $ which means if I replaced one power in the demonstrator with higher value than the $AM-GM$ form then $z$ is unbounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(x, y) = (t^d, t^c)$ with $t > 0$ is
$$
  \frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d} =  \frac{t^{ad+bc}}{2t^{cd}}
$$
so that a necessary condition for boundedness at the origin is $ad+bc \ge cd$, i.e.
$$
 \boxed{ \frac ac + \frac bd \ge 1 }\, .
$$
Conversely, if $s = \frac ac + \frac bd  \ge 1$ then
$$ 
 \alpha = \frac{a}{sc} \, , \, \beta = \frac{b}{sd}
$$
are positive with $\alpha + \beta = 1$, and
$$
 x^a y^b = \left( (x^c)^{\alpha} \cdot (y^d)^{\beta}\right)^s 
 \le \left( \alpha x^c + \beta y^d\right)^s 
 \le \left( x^c + y^d\right)^s
$$
by the weighted AM-GM inequality, so that $\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d}$ is bounded near the origin.

---

*Remark:* In the same way one can show that
$$
\lim_{\substack{(x,y) \to (0,0) \\ x> 0, y > 0}} \frac{x^a y^b}{x^c + y^d} = 0
$$
if and only if $\frac ac + \frac bd > 1$.

Comment: how does $x^a y^b = \left( (x^c)^{\alpha} + (y^d)^{\beta}\right)^s $

Comment: @pie: That was my mistake, I have fixed it. Hopefully everything is correct now!

Comment: thank you very much